# RAM appears as single pair, not as 4 modules

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a problem with RAM memory modules. One pair of 2GB modules (lets call them `1` and `2`) works fine in my PC. I tried to install 2 more 2GB pieces (lets call them `3` and `4`) as a second pair, but the PC wont boot. More oddly, when I remove the first pair (`1 and 2`), the second pair (`3` and `4`) works fine.

I've tried every possible permutation as a 4 piece group (`1, 2, 3, 4`, `1, 3, 4, 2` and so on), and the computer wont boot in any of them. On the other hand, I've also tried every single pair combination (`1, 2`, `2, 4` and so on) and the computer worked fine every time

All the modules are the same model.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cmos? What is the MB model?

Comment: Is the max memory for the machine 4gb?  What exactly do you mean by "won't boot"

Comment: Please answer the four questions above, plus: 5) When you turn on the PC and go into the BIOS/Firmware settings, what appears in the memory section? 6) After you cleared the CMOS settings, did you select default settings? Please click [edit] and answer items 1-6. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please click on [edit].